# After a Windows Crash, ASP.NET Core App Is No Longer Accessible Docker Desktop (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, docker-desktop

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 app that I've been debugging in Visual Studio 2022 with Docker Desktop for the past few months. Everything has been running fine with no issues up until this morning. This morning, my Windows machine crashed. When it came back up, something... 'broke'. First off, when I restarted Docker Desktop after the crash, it just sat on "Docker Desktop starting" for 10 minutes before I killed the process and started it again. The second time it came up and ran normally. When I started the Visual Studio debugger, it connected to Docker Desktop and created a container normally. But when it opened the Swagger page in my browser like normal, this is all I see:

[image]

Similarly, when I click on the "Open with browser" link on the container in Docker Desktop, I see the same error. And it's not just my browser. I can't connect to the app with my standalone test app either.

I've tried restarting my computer, cleaning and rebuilding the app, deleting the Docker container,  deleting the Docker image, uninstalling/reinstalling Docker Desktop, but nothing works.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Update: after more experimentation, it's not a Docker Desktop issue. I can change Visual Studio's debug target to "IIS Express" and I still get the same error. So, it *feels* like something Windows-ish is amiss here. I have no idea...

On the plus side, I can change the debug target to run in a console, and that works just fine! So, at least I can keep developing.